# FaunaDB crud events / triggers

Tags: faunadb

I'm evaluating FaunaDB as a replacement for DynamoDB.

Is there such thing as database triggers for this database? I cannot find any reference relative to that.

For example, upon document insertion or update, can we trigger a specific function, for example to call x external service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger functionality is not available currently but is being worked on high priority. Meanwhile, users can still write a fql user defined functions to poll the events (as close to real time) and trigger a specific function. Let us know if need more assistance with it.